# query a dataframe with conditions in two columns with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['840', '007658', 'EP010A', 'wrwrwr'],
 ['841', '007658', 'EP019410A', 'wwtert'],
 ['842', '007658', 'EP0129W', 'erterte'],
 ['843', '007658', 'EP0629W', 'ertetet'],
 ['992', '007675', 'EP0275A', 'ete'],
 ['993', '007675', 'EP0375A', 'ertre'],
 ['994', '007675', 'EP02091', 'ert'],
 ['117', '007690', 'EP02212A', 'sf'],
 ['118', '007690', 'EP00212A', 'sf'],
 ['118', '007690', 'EP02281W', 'dg'],
 ['118', '007690', 'EP07281W', 'dg'],
 ['118', '007690', 'EP0281W', 'sdf'],
 ['118', '007690', 'EP02281W', 'ert'],
 ['118', '007690', 'EP0612A', 'dfg'],
 ['11', '0076', 'US0612A', 'dfg'],
 ['12', '0076', 'CA0612A', 'dfg']], columns = ['i', 'fn','docn','ad'])
```

I would like to create a dataframe that contain all the data which complies the following condition.
for the same fn number there should be at least one docn number starting with EP and not ending with W and one docn number starting with EP and ending with W:

For instance the fn nr 007658 has docn EP010A  EP019410A  EP0129W     EP0629W which qualifies
nevertheless 007675 does not qualify because it does not contain any value in docn that starts with EP and ends with W.
fn '0076' does not qualify neither since tehre is no single docn corresponding doc starting by EP.

I am trying a million things with groupby fn but nothing works.

For instance:

```
for i,group in enumerate(df2.groupby("fn")):
    display(group)
    has_EP  = group[1]['docn'].apply(lambda docns: any(docn.startswith('EP') and not docn.endswith('W') for docn in docns))
    has_EP_W= group[1]['docn'].apply(lambda docns: any(docn.startswith('EP') and docn.endswith('W') for docn in docns))
    total_condition =has_EP & has_EP_W
    
    display(group[1]['docn'].loc[total_condition])
    
    if i==3:
        break
```

does not work.

Comment: Could you please explain why `007675` did not qualify?

Comment: I edit the question, I manually have created the data and indeed there was a mistake

Comment: desired output is to filter the data according to the aforementioned conditions, correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

edit with @Asish M. comment

```
cond1 = df['docn'].str.contains(r'^EP.+W$').groupby(df['fn']).transform(any)
cond2 = df['docn'].str.contains(r'^EP.+[^W]$').groupby(df['fn']).transform(any)
out = df[cond1 & cond2]
```

out

```
    i      fn       docn       ad
0   840  007658     EP010A   wrwrwr
1   841  007658  EP019410A   wwtert
2   842  007658    EP0129W  erterte
3   843  007658    EP0629W  ertetet
7   117  007690   EP02212A       sf
8   118  007690   EP00212A       sf
9   118  007690   EP02281W       dg
10  118  007690   EP07281W       dg
11  118  007690    EP0281W      sdf
12  118  007690   EP02281W      ert
13  118  007690    EP0612A      dfg
```

Comment: the 2nd regex should be `[^W]` instead of `A` since they mention "not ending with W" as opposed to "ending with A"

Comment: @AsishM. Thank you for your feedback. It seems that the original example only consisted of W and A, which may have led to some misunderstanding regarding the conditions.